# I want to write to a certain line in a txt file using php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php 
$myFile="file.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);
echo $lines[1];
?>
```

This is how i will be reading line 2.
However now what i want is to be able to also write in line 2
I tried that:

```
<?php 
    $LineToWriteTo = 1;
    $lines[$LineToWriteTo] = "Text!";
?>
```

Comment: `$lines[$LineToWriteTo] = "Text!";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$myFile = "file.txt";
$txt = '';
$file = file($myFile);
foreach ($file as $row_num => $row) {
    if ($row_num == 1) {
        $txt .= 'line 2';
    } else {
        $txt .= $row_num . '-' . $row . '<br>';
    }
}
$file_o = fopen($myFile, "w");
fwrite($file_o, $txt);
fclose($file_o);
```